# Bake only set keyframes to .fbx file?

Tags: animation, .fbx

Is there a way to only bake your current set keyframes to a .fbx file instead of generating a bunch of keyframes for every point of the animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty workaround: Save a copy of your file, delete the unwanted keyframes, and export.

Comment: Is there a cleaner option?